# Why is erase function giving a runtime error?

Tags: vector, stl

```
vector<int> a;
a.push_back(0);

int n = a.size();


int cnt = 0;
for (auto itr = a.begin(); itr != a.end(); itr++)
{
    if(*itr == 0)
    {
        cnt++;
        a.erase(itr); 
    }
}
```

The code is working on inserting numbers other than zero.
The line `a.erase(itr)` is giving a runtime error for some reason.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with *erase* you modify the *vector* so the iterator become invalid, a solution modifying a little your code :

```
  vector<int> a;
  a.push_back(0);

  int n=a.size();
  int cnt=0;
  auto itr=a.begin();

  while (itr != a.end()) 
  {
    if(*itr == 0)
    {
      cnt++;
      itr = a.erase(itr); 
    }
    else
      ++itr;
  }
```

Note the right type for *n*  and *count* is `size_type` rather than *int*